# How to fix "Cannot find form control with name: __v" error in angular form control?

Tags: node.js, angular, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose for my application's backend. Whenever I try to save data with my API, an additional column is added called `__v`. I went through their documentation and noticed that the extra field is for versioning.

I have a CRUD in my angular front end application. Whenever I do a get request, I get the below error message.

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find form control with name: __v.
    at FormGroup.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroup._throwIfControlMissing (forms.js:3605)
    at forms.js:3462
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at FormGroup.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroup.setValue (forms.js:3461)
    at EmployeeService.push../src/app/services/employee.service.ts.EmployeeService.load (employee.service.ts:54)
    at EmployeesComponent.push../src/app/components/employees/employees.component.ts.EmployeesComponent.onEdit (employees.component.ts:47)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (EmployeesComponent.html:81)
    at handleEvent (core.js:19545)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:20639)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:20342)
```

Some suggestions were to remove the creation of `__v` field in the collections. But I would like to retain the field and still make sure there are no errors. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: can you share your component code

Comment: Please post your html code. It's looks you are trying to access property which is never existing in variable so you have to use [] or ?.

Answer (score 4):

Use `patchValue()` instead of `setValue()`

> component.ts

```
this.myForm.patchValue(responce)
```